# Doubly ruled surfaces by quasi-orthogonal lines

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, geometric-measure-theory

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/250128/doubly-ruled-surfaces) question, it is asked how to prove that a doubly ruled surface by orthogonal lines is a plane.

I'm interested if this property is robust under perturbations of the angle the lines make; that is, suppose that we have a doubly ruled surface by lines which meet at angle $\theta$, where $\theta>0$ (so in the case of the question above, $\theta= \pi/2$). This $\theta$ is assumed to be fixed everywhere on the surface.

**Question:** with this assumption, can we conclude that the surface is a plane?

Any comment is appreciated!

Comment: Compute the Gaussian curvature which has simple expression for ruled surfaces (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2507529)

Comment: This problem can be approached particularly effectively using differential forms and moving frames.

Comment: @TedShifrin I'm not terribly familiar with these techniques. Could you point out a reference? Thanks!

Comment: There's a brief section on moving frames in my differential geometry text (linked in my profile). You might look at a wonderful new book by Jeanne Cleland, *From Frenet to Cartan: The Method of Moving Frames*. However, maybe you should just use Gauss-Bonnet in a straightforward manner to show that $K=0$ everywhere. Then you still have to deduce the second fundamental form is $0$.